# How to get rid of comma if no other value comes after the string

Tags: sql-server

I would like to not have a comma when there is a no value after string but I keep getting back a comma even if there is a value

[image]

```
  select 
                company_no,
                company_name, 
                concat(address_1 
                         ,CASE WHEN NULLIF(address_1,'') <> ''  THEN ', ' 
                               ELSE '' 
                          END) + concat(address_2
                         ,CASE WHEN NULLIF(address_2,'')<> ''  THEN ', ' 
                               ELSE '' 
                          END) + concat(address_3
                         ,CASE WHEN NULLIF(address_3,'')<> '' THEN ', ' 

                               ELSE '' 
                          END)+
                           concat(address_4
                         ,CASE WHEN NULLIF(address_4,'')<> ''  THEN ', ' 
                               ELSE '' 
                          END)+
                           concat(address_5
                         ,CASE WHEN NULLIF(address_5,'')<> ''  THEN ' ' 
                               ELSE '' 
                          END) as Address,
                code.code_desc as company_status

                from company_tbl company
                inner join code_tbl code on company.company_status = code.code and code.code_type = 'COM' and code_sub_type = 'CIR'


                where company_name like company_name +'%'
                and company_type = 'EOC'
                and address_3 is null
```

What I am getting :

1. 3050 LakedTest,, CityTest
2. TBC,
3. NULL

Desired output

1. 3050 LakedTest,CityTest
2. TBC
3. (Want this just to be blank)

Update : I had to add a the `REPLACE` function to get rid of commas that were in the String values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [STUFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function, or if your server version is 2017 or higher just use [CONCAT_WS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-ws-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (
    address_1   VARCHAR(10),
    address_2   VARCHAR(10),
    address_3   VARCHAR(10),
    address_4   VARCHAR(10),
    address_5   VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT @Test
VALUES
('AAA', 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE'),
(NULL, 'BBB', 'CCC', 'DDD', 'EEE'),
(NULL, NULL, NULL, 'DDD', 'EEE'),
(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'EEE'),
('AAA', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'EEE'),
('AAA', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)

SELECT 
ISNULL(
    STUFF(
        CONCAT ( 
            ', ' + NULLIF(REPLACE(address_1, ',', ''), ''),
            ', ' + NULLIF(REPLACE(address_2, ',', ''), ''),
            ', ' + NULLIF(REPLACE(address_3, ',', ''), ''),
            ', ' + NULLIF(REPLACE(address_4, ',', ''), ''),
            ', ' + NULLIF(REPLACE(address_5, ',', ''), '')
        ),
        1,
        2,
        ''
    ),
    ''
)
FROM @Test
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select company_no,
       company_name, 
       COALESCE(concat_ws(', ',
                          NULLIF(address_1,''),
                          NULLIF(address_2,''),
                          NULLIF(address_3,''),
                          NULLIF(address_4,''),
                          NULLIF(address_5,'')), '') as Address,
       code.code_desc as company_status

from company_tbl company
inner join code_tbl code on company.company_status = code.code 
                        and code.code_type = 'COM' 
                        and code_sub_type = 'CIR'

where company_name like company_name +'%' -- ???
  and company_type = 'EOC'
  and address_3 is null -- ???
```

---

`company_name like company_name +'%'` is extremely strange - it is always true except the case when `company_name` is NULL.

`and address_3 is null` is strange too - more precise it is strange why this field is nevertheless included into output expression.

Comment: This part `company_name like company_name +'%'`, this is used to populate a repeating table in an application, so you if type for e.g Intel, it will get all the companies like intel and populate into a table on the application side.

Comment: @Rachel ??? It may be true in a form similar to `@company_name like company_name +'%'`, where `@company_name` is a string parameter transferred to a query by code. In shown expression it is a field value, moreover, the value of a field in the same record - so it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Is this due to comparing NULL values? For instance, instead of saying

```
CASE WHEN NULLIF(address_2,'') <> '' THEN ', ' ELSE '' END
```

Would you rather say

```
CASE WHEN ISNULL(NULLIF(address_2,''),'1') <> '1' THEN ', ' ELSE '' END
```

Using ISNULL avoids the issue of comparing NULL values since you're now setting the expression equal to 1 if it's NULL, then comparing 1 to 1. SQL does not know how to compare NULL to NULL, and so any statement comparing NULLs will always evaluate to TRUE.

Edit: had the wrong comparison operator in the second statement, should be <>.